# stderr log4j:WARN Attribute "name" is required and must be specified for element type "category".?

Tags: logging, log4j

i am using log4j in java application with jboss eap 6, i have configured the `log4j.xml` with below configuration.

```
<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/" debug="null" threshold="null">
<appender name="INFO_FILE" class="org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender">
        <param name="File" value="mypath/myLogs.log"/>  
        <param name="DatePattern" value="'.'MM-dd-yy"/>
        <layout class="class path here">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{ISO8601} %c{2} %m%n"/>
        </layout>
    </appender>

<category>
  <priority value="OFF" />
</category>

    <root>
        <level value="INFO" />
        <appender-ref ref="INFO_FILE"/>
    </root>
</log4j:configuration>
```

but i am getting below error in log statements

```
stderr log4j:WARN Attribute "name" is required and must be specified for element type "category".
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should specify the `name=""` attribute to the `category` element, like stdout or something else

```
<category name="STDOUT">
  <priority value="OFF" />
</category>
```